# Edit Action parameters programmatically

Tags: adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Is it possible to edit the parameters of an Illustrator action programmatically? I'd like to change a "simplify curve" action's tolerance via Javascript. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create action file with desired parameters, and load it in illustrator.
Check here for example: https://gist.github.com/moluapple/2568405